# Scipy Gumbel Fit does not Fit - What is the correct use?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics

I'm trying to fit various distributions onto my [data](https://gist.github.com/Mortom123/f35b565d5bed0c6763db3408c574cb79) and test (chi-squared?) which fits best. I started out by using the `gumbel_r` distribution of scipy, as this is the one often used in literature.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as ss

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
data

sns.histplot(data["score"], kde=True, stat='probability')
plt.show()

x = np.linspace(0,1,101)
hist, bins = np.histogram(data["score"], bins=x, density=True)
loc, scale = ss.gumbel_r.fit(hist)
dist = ss.gumbel_r(loc=loc,scale=scale)
plt.plot(x, dist.pdf(x))
plt.show()
```

Inspecting the plots yields strange results. For example my data has a peak at ~0.09 of around ~0.025. However, the plotted gumbel looks completely off.

My questions are now:

1. Why are the plots not looking similar? I'm also suspecting `stat='probability'` could be the culprit here?
2. What do I need to do, such that the second plot will look somewhat similar to the first one?
3. Optimally I would get another `hist` for the same bins of the fitted distribution and input into `scipy.stats.chisquare` to quantify how good the fit of the distribution is and see which fits best. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't give `hist` to `gumbel_r.fit()`.  It expects the original data.  Change the line that calls `fit()` to

```
loc, scale = ss.gumbel_r.fit(data['score'].to_numpy())
```

Also, to get the Seaborn plot on the same scale as the plot of the PDF, change `stat='probability'` to `stat='density'` in the `histplot()` call.

Comment: Is my assumption, that I call `ss.chisquare(hist,dist.pdf(x)[:-1])` afterwards correct?